# Apache spawning workers even though there's almost no access

Tags: apache-2.4, wordpress, mpm-prefork

Lately Apache has been spawning workers even though there seems to be no reason for it. After ~10 minutes of a restart, it keeps spawning workers until it reaches the maximum number and new requests are never served.

After a service restart (`service apache2 restart`) I started monitoring the access log. There were only two rather simple requests before it started spawning workers like a madman:

```
#/var/log/apache2/access.log

66.249.64.215 - - [17/Feb/2016:00:30:18 +0000] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2015/08/colarinho_3.png HTTP/1.1" 304 179 "-" "Googlebot-Image/1.0"
201.80.103.196 - - [17/Feb/2016:00:33:00 +0000] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2015/09/circulo_cromatico.png HTTP/1.1" 200 40642 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0"
```

And here's the fullstatus before it completely stopped serving new requests.

```
$apache2ctl fullstatus
                  Apache Server Status for localhost (via ::1)

   Server Version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.12
   Server MPM: prefork
   Server Built: Jul 24 2015 17:25:11
     __________________________________________________________________

   Current Time: Wednesday, 17-Feb-2016 00:35:57 UTC
   Restart Time: Wednesday, 17-Feb-2016 00:26:33 UTC
   Parent Server Config. Generation: 1
   Parent Server MPM Generation: 0
   Server uptime: 9 minutes 24 seconds
   Server load: 0.00 0.06 0.18
   Total accesses: 3 - Total Traffic: 48 kB
   CPU Usage: u0 s0 cu0 cs0
   .00532 requests/sec - 87 B/second - 16.0 kB/request
   22 requests currently being processed, 4 idle workers

WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW_WW___........................

   Scoreboard Key:
   "_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
   "W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
   "C" Closing connection, "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing,
   "I" Idle cleanup of worker, "." Open slot with no current process

   Srv PID Acc M CPU SS Req Conn Child Slot Client VHost Request
   0-0 6980 0/0/0 W 0.00 64 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/191.185.144.200 HTTP/1.0
   1-0 6981 0/1/1 W 0.00 55 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.0
   2-0 6982 0/1/1 W 0.00 52 0 0.0 0.04 0.04 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.0
   3-0 6983 0/0/0 W 0.00 65 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 191.185.144.200
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET / HTTP/1.1
   4-0 6984 0/0/0 W 0.00 64 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.0
   5-0 6989 0/0/0 W 0.00 55 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.0
   6-0 6990 0/0/0 W 0.00 50 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.0
   7-0 6991 0/0/0 W 0.00 41 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.0
   8-0 6992 0/0/0 W 0.00 50 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.0
   9-0 6993 0/0/0 W 0.00 40 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.0
   10-0 6994 0/0/0 W 0.00 38 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.0
   11-0 6995 0/0/0 W 0.00 35 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.0
   12-0 6996 0/0/0 W 0.00 24 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.0
   13-0 6997 0/0/0 W 0.00 32 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.0
   14-0 6998 0/0/0 W 0.00 24 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.0
   15-0 6999 0/0/0 W 0.00 24 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.0
   16-0 7000 0/0/0 W 0.00 11 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.0
   17-0 7001 0/0/0 W 0.00 7 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.0
   18-0 7002 0/0/0 W 0.00 7 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.0
   19-0 7003 0/0/0 W 0.00 4 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.0
   20-0 7004 0/1/1 _ 0.00 7 0 0.0 0.01 0.01 ::1 socialtailor.com.br:80 GET
   /server-status HTTP/1.0
   21-0 7005 0/0/0 W 0.00 2 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 127.0.0.1
   socialtailor.com.br:80 GET /lookup/127.0.0.1 HTTP/1.0
   22-0 7006 0/0/0 W 0.00 0 0 0.0 0.00 0.00 ::1 socialtailor.com.br:80 GET
   /server-status HTTP/1.0
     __________________________________________________________________

    Srv  Child Server number - generation
    PID  OS process ID
    Acc  Number of accesses this connection / this child / this slot
     M   Mode of operation
    CPU  CPU usage, number of seconds
    SS   Seconds since beginning of most recent request
    Req  Milliseconds required to process most recent request
   Conn  Kilobytes transferred this connection
   Child Megabytes transferred this child
   Slot  Total megabytes transferred this slot
     __________________________________________________________________


    Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

The site it is serving has a Wordpress installation. I updated it to the newest version and disabled cron jobs. Any idea why this is happening or how to debug this further?

Further strange thing: if I do a `lynx http://localhost/` it keeps waiting for a response forever (even if Apache is not overloaded with workers) and then immediately Apache starts spawning a lot of workers, just like before.

I am using mpm_prefork with the following conf:

```
#/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers            5
    MinSpareServers         5
    MaxSpareServers         10
    MaxRequestWorkers       50
    MaxConnectionsPerChild  1000
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What method are you using to execute your PHP? If you are not using mod_php, then you should definitely update to the event mpm? Also you could repeatedly request the /server-status?auto URL to see if you are running out of workers (also check the Apache error log as it will log an entry there if you are not)